# Kotlin Android Studio - load thumbnails from newsapi

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using this [news api](https://newsapi.org/) to pull the json data into my app and render it in my `articlerecycler` adapter class. 
From the api there is a json value `urlToImage` that contains the thumbnail that I need to render. Currently I have a working list of 20 or so articles displaying the author, title, description, etc.

What is the best way to show the thumbnails as well?
Is using `ImageView` widget the best way to handle this?

For example,

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailIv"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/urlToImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder_image" />
```

I've found through other posts that picasso is a good way to lazy load images, specifically thumbnails.

```
    // load the image with Picasso
    Picasso.get()
            .load("") // load the image
            .into(thumbnailIv) // select the ImageVi

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use `ImageView` and use library like `Glide` or `picasso` to load image into `ImageView` from the url

```
 GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA) //optional
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)  //optional
            .error(R.drawable.default_image)  //optional
            .into(holder.imageNews);
```

With ImageView you can control `ScaleType` another useful property is `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` which will maintain aspect ratio . If you use use linear/relative and set image as background then you cannot control these properties

Comment: `.with` looks like it might be deprecated. I have updated my question with my findings using `picasso`.